# pip instal math3d - EROR

Tags: python, pip, installation, python-3.7

I am geting a constant error while trying to isntall math3d or urx libary for Python using pip install. I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.3.

I tried to:
- uninstall/install python and also try an older version 3.4.4.. nothing worked.
- upgrade setuptools
- upgrade pip (then I get even more errors)

Here is my error:

```
C:\Users\alen.kolman\Desktop\math3d-3.3.4>pip install math3d
Collecting math3d
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/33/72ac95bb4ac11a2b13e033d90f84430dc23fc815124d9303dffca8789a75/math3d-3.3.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: math3d
  Running setup.py install for math3d ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ALEN~1.KOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jihuupoe\\math3d\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ALEN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3r05scnh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\orientation.py -> build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\orientation_computer.py -> build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\quaternion.py -> build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\transform.py -> build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\utils.py -> build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\vector.py -> build\lib\math3d
    copying math3d\__init__.py -> build\lib\math3d
    creating build\lib\math3d\interpolation
    copying math3d\interpolation\r3interpolation.py -> build\lib\math3d\interpolation
    copying math3d\interpolation\se3interpolation.py -> build\lib\math3d\interpolation
    copying math3d\interpolation\so3interpolation.py -> build\lib\math3d\interpolation
    copying math3d\interpolation\__init__.py -> build\lib\math3d\interpolation
    creating build\lib\math3d\reference_system
    copying math3d\reference_system\frame.py -> build\lib\math3d\reference_system
    copying math3d\reference_system\free_vector.py -> build\lib\math3d\reference_system
    copying math3d\reference_system\point.py -> build\lib\math3d\reference_system
    copying math3d\reference_system\reference_system.py -> build\lib\math3d\reference_system
    copying math3d\reference_system\__init__.py -> build\lib\math3d\reference_system
    creating build\lib\math3d\dynamics
    copying math3d\dynamics\twist.py -> build\lib\math3d\dynamics
    copying math3d\dynamics\wrench.py -> build\lib\math3d\dynamics
    copying math3d\dynamics\__init__.py -> build\lib\math3d\dynamics
    creating build\lib\math3d\geometry
    copying math3d\geometry\line.py -> build\lib\math3d\geometry
    copying math3d\geometry\plane.py -> build\lib\math3d\geometry
    copying math3d\geometry\__init__.py -> build\lib\math3d\geometry
    running install_lib
    running install_data
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ALEN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jihuupoe\math3d\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        data_files=[('share/doc/pymath3d/', ['README.md', 'COPYING'])]
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 557, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\command\install_data.py", line 56, in run
        dir = convert_path(f[0])
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\util.py", line 112, in convert_path
        raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname)
    ValueError: path 'share/doc/pymath3d/' cannot end with '/'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ALEN~1.KOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jihuupoe\\math3d\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ALEN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3r05scnh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ALEN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jihuupoe\math3d\
```

Comment: I successfully installed `math3d` on Linux for Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.7. Perhaps it's a w32-related problem about right slashes instead of backslashes. Report the bug to their issue tracker.

Comment: Also try the following: clone [the repository](https://gitlab.com/morlin/pymath3d), edit `setup.py` and remove [the trailing slash](https://gitlab.com/morlin/pymath3d/blob/75fea9e3d7bc93ec6f72f9b293625a023b11aa95/setup.py#L23), then run `pip install .`

Comment: @phd.. thank's for your answer. I am using win10-64bit... I tryed Python 32 and 64 bit (get the same eror) ! I manage to install pip install numpy, but pip install urx and pip install math3d make eror!                                                                     What you mean by edit setup.py (change / to \ ??) and remove the trailing slash ?  Because pip install numpy is using  right slashes.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have trailing slashes in its [`setup.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py) but `math3d` has one. Try to remove it and install.

Comment: thank you! now it work without erors!!

Comment: @phd add this as an answer, so it shows as answered.

Comment: The authors [fixed](https://gitlab.com/morlin/pymath3d/commit/3fb373e4efd8614a7dbbad4dbf7d66ad6bf6272d) the problem just half a day ago. :-)